# newline in description of `newglossaryentry`

Tags: lists, line-breaking, glossaries

How is it possible to get a newline at the beginning of the description?
So the description starts at second line?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,english,ngerman,numbers=noenddot, headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{NIS}{
    name={NIS}, 
    description={Name Information Service \\* see \ref{subsec:nis} \nameref{subsec:nis}}
}

\newglossaryentry{Test}{
    name={Test}, 
    description={\\* This is a Test}
}


\begin{document}

\subsection{Name Information Service}
\label{subsec:nis}
A long big text about \gls{NIS}
A short text about \gls{Test}


\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

MWE Error:

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.8 ...etentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{1}}}
                                                  %
```

Comment: It depends on your glossary style. You need to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot sorry for that, done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default glossary style (`list`) uses the `description` environment which doesn't like a line break immediately after `\item`. Your second entry has a line break at the start of the description which tries to break the line immediately after `\item`, which is what's causing the problem. You can add an empty box immediately before the line break (which is what the `altlist` style does to force the description on the line below the item):

```
\documentclass[11pt,english,ngerman,numbers=noenddot,headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{NIS}{
    name={NIS}, 
    description={Name Information Service \\* see \ref{subsec:nis}
\nameref{subsec:nis}}
}

\newglossaryentry{Test}{
    name={Test}, 
    description={\mbox{}\\* This is a Test}
}


\begin{document}

\subsection{Name Information Service}
\label{subsec:nis}
A long big text about \gls{NIS}
A short text about \gls{Test}


\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: thx a lot, tried whitespaces and http://latex.wikia.com/wiki/White_space but nothing works

Comment: @Megachip: A non-breakiong space (in TeX `~`) would have worked.