# Glossary styling. How to stop terms from overlapping the definitions?

Tags: glossaries, overleaf, html, glossary

I have created a simple Glossary for my article, but one of the terms being defined (Guidelines) is rendered written over its definition. This way it is illegible, as you can see on the screenshot below:

[image: Glossary overlapping]

I need a way to stop this mess and get a legible Glossary, but I don't know how to do it on LaTeX. Can someone please suggest me possible ways to fix this?

**A rendering just like the default HTML Description List rendering is welcome:**

The first solutuion for fixing the Glossary was to make it work just like a [HTML Description List](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl), because these, by default, put the description on the line below the term being described, not right in front of it. This way, the term being defined will never be able to touch its definition.

Below I show [the Mozilla Developer example of how a HTML Description List is rendered by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl):
[image: How I would appreciate my Glossary being rendered]

This solution (inserting a line break after each term being defined) would be sufficient an very much satisfactory. I just don't know how to do the trick on LaTeX (Overleaf).

**Which LaTeX code did I use to make my broken Glossary?**

This one:

```
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{Guidelines}
{
    name=\textsc{Guidelines},
    description={The article ``Guidelines for performing Systematic Literature Reviews in Software Engineering"\cite{keele2007guidelines} that is used as the methodological basis for this entire review}
}

\newglossaryentry{SLR}
{
    name=\textsc{SLR},
    description={Systematic Literature Review}
}

\printglossary[title=Acronyms and Abbreviations, toctitle=List of acronyms and abbreviations]
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.SE, BsAx... (longest one I've seen here so far )

Comment: Thank you @mickep .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

- `\mbox{}` allows a line break `\\` to be inserted on the beginning of the description.
- This fixes eventual overlaps, but is not the most elegant solution if you want all of the definitions on a new line, like the HTML `DL` does by default.
- An elegant solution for doing this is welcome... But maybe deserve a dedicated question on Stack Exchange, for better scoping? I'm not sure.

**Explanation:** I found [the following trick pointed by Nicola Talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164436/283597) 9 years ago:

```
\newglossaryentry{Test}{
    name={Test}, 
    description={\mbox{}\\* This is a Test}
}
```

As he wrote:

> The default glossary style (`list`) uses the `description` environment which doesn't like a line break immediately after `\item`.
>
> You can add an empty box immediately before the line break (which is what the `altlist` style does to force the description on the line below the item).